# Facebook C# login with my account and pwd and post question

Tags: c#, facebook

Does anybody have example?

```
FacebookUser.Login="John";
FacebookUser.PasswordOrEmail="123";
FacebookUser.Connect();
FacebookUser.PostToWall("Hi dude");
```

I tried FacebookSdk (from codeplex) but it use OAUTH and javascript controls (user need enter login,pwd)

I need to keep my login and pwd in appsettings or Class property.
I know that there are Facebook Graph, and Facebook Connect. Maybe you have samples related to this task?

Comment: To have code formatted as code, you have to put four spaces before each line. There is a button for it as well and it looks like this: `{}`. I did that for you this time.

Comment: to paste code from a program, one can also use a `<pre><code> … </code></pre>` block.

Comment: @Felix: Please don't suggest `<pre><code>`, it doesn't work anywhere near as well as the built-in Markdown code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

This is a big violation of Facebook's Terms of Service. You do not want to do this. Instead, use the OAuth and request the 'offline_access' extended permission. This permission will give you an access token that does not expire. This way you can save the access token and use it even when the user is not logged in. If you get caught asking for the user's username and password Facebook will remove your app.

Comment: It is not application. It is my own login and pwd. For example i want to post article to twitter,facebook and my own siti,I wrote on my site ("Article HEY") an this script will post this article to fb,twitter.I just need simple source code(if it use oauth okay)

Answer (score 0):

You need to post to user feed url /me/feed on facebook.